# Jquery Selectize Add "Clear All" link at the top of options from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I am using Jquery's [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) tagging library which works well for me so far.

Below is the code I have used.

**Javascript Code:**

```
$('#q').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    valueField: 'address',
    labelField: 'address',
    searchField: 'address',                 
    create: true,    
    render: {
        item: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div>' + escape(data.address) + '</div>';
        }

    },
    onChange: function(value) {
      $(".selectize-input input[placeholder]").attr("style", "width: 100%;");
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url:  base_url + '/search-property-autocomplete',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                q: query,

            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res.properties);
                callback(res.properties);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
/* API for autocomplete list of properties */
Route::post('/search-property-autocomplete', function () {
    if (!empty(trim($_POST['q']))) {
        $search_term = trim($_POST['q']);


        // getting Suburb State and Postcode of the properties based on search 
        $query = Property::join('technobrave_suburbs_', function($join) {

                    $join->on('technobrave_properties_.suburb_id', '=', 'technobrave_suburbs_.id');
                });

        $query->join('technobrave_states_', function($join) {
            $join->on('technobrave_properties_.state_id', '=', 'technobrave_states_.id');
        });


        $query->select('technobrave_properties_.*', 'technobrave_suburbs_.suburb', 'technobrave_states_.state_name');

        $query->where(function($query) use ($search_term) {
            $query->where('technobrave_properties_.post_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_term . '%');
            $query->orwhere('technobrave_suburbs_.suburb', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_term . '%');
            $query->orwhere('technobrave_states_.state_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_term . '%');
        });
        $data = $query->take(8)->get(); // getting maximum 8 records only 

        if ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $current_record) {
                $result[] = array(
                    'address' => $current_record->suburb . ' ' . $current_record->state_name . ' ' . $current_record->post_code
                );
            }
        }
    } else {
        $result = [];
    }
    echo json_encode(array('properties' => $result));
});
```

As you can see in above code, I am using Ajax to populate data and getting records by calling my php function which is working absolutely fine.

Now, I want to append one item as a hyperlink at the top of my all the results something like **Clear All** which will come every time I search or type in my input-box.

And IF I click on **Clear All** link, the results which appended below should be cleared.

To use the [`clearoptions()`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) event provided by Selectize, I have updated my `create:` in my JavaScript code with:

```
create: function(input, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url:  base_url + '/search-property-autocomplete',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: query,

        },
        error: function() {
            callback();
        },
        success: function(res) {

            return callback({ address: "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Clear All</a>" });

        }
    });


},
```

But it seems to be not working as I am unable to see my added option there. I am unable to see my Hyperlink after my results populate.

I already know using somethink like below code will remove my populated records after I search.

```
$('.my-hyperlink-custom-class').on('click', function() {
    control.clearOptions();
});
```

But I am stuck appending or pushing this new item to my code with the results I populate using Ajax.

Can someone guide me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much to all for help and support. And special thanks to [@afeique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371871/6829420)'s hint to implement this feature.

Here is the solution I eventually came up with.

```
$('#q').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    valueField: 'address',
    labelField: 'address',
    searchField: 'address',                 
    create: true,    
    render: {
        item: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div>' + escape(data.address) + '</div>';
        }

    },
    onChange: function(value) {
      $(".selectize-input input[placeholder]").attr("style", "width: 100%;");
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();

        // Appending only if not exists 
        if($('.clearAllSuggestions').length == 0) {
            $(".selectize-dropdown").append('<a href="#" class="clearAllSuggestions">Clear All</a>');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:  base_url + '/search-property-autocomplete',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                q: query,

            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res.properties);
                callback(res.properties);
            }
        });
    }
});


$('body').on('click', '.clearAllSuggestions', function() {

    var $select = $('#q').selectize({});
    var control = $select[0].selectize;
    control.clearCache('option');
    control.clearOptions();
    control.refreshOptions(true);
});
```

I modified my code a bit and put below code in my `load` event to append "Clear All" anchor tag in my suggestion tag options.

```
// Appending only if not exists 
        if($('.clearAllSuggestions').length == 0) {
            $(".selectize-dropdown").append('<a href="#" class="clearAllSuggestions">Clear All</a>');
        }
```

Then, I simply wanted to clear cache and options hence I put below code.

```
$('body').on('click', '.clearAllSuggestions', function() {

    var $select = $('#q').selectize({});
    var control = $select[0].selectize;
    control.clearCache('option');
    control.clearOptions();
    control.refreshOptions(true);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the script I wrote. This will change all the `href` attribute above the selected one with the `javascript:;` while the below one will remain the same.You can modify this as per your need.

```js
$(".row").click(function(){
var present =  $(this).index();
console.log("present"+present)
 $(this).closest('.container').find('.row').each(function(index,element){
  console.log("eachindex"+$(this).index());
  if($(this).index()>=present) {
   
  }
  else {
   $(this).attr("href","javascript:;");
  }
 })
 $(".row").each(function(){
  $("#finalAttribute").append($(this).attr("href"));
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a class="row row1" href="#1">
  R1
  </a>
  <br/>
    <a class="row row2" href="#2">
  R1
  </a>
    <br/>
    <a class="row row3" href="#3">
  R2
  </a>
    <br/>
    <a class="row row4" href="#4">
  R3
  </a>
    <br/>
          <a class="row row5" href="#5">
  R4
  </a>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="finalAttribute">


</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this method, I believe your issue is with DOM rendering and binding JS functions. since the element is not available on load, the element cannot by bind with javascript. below method will work.

```
$('body').on('click', '.my-hyperlink-custom-class', function() {
    control.clearOptions();
});
```

Here i have have bind the function to body, however im again checking if target element is .my-hyperlink-custom-class.

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me, I don't have experience with Selectize but I did scan through their [examples](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) and noticed something that may be helpful:

```
$('#input-tags3').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
```

In this example, the `create:` has function prototype `function(input)` which only has one argument and no callback function. Your code is using the following prototype: `create: function(input, callback)`. From the Selectize examples, I have only seen `load:` use `function(input, callback)`.

I would suggest altering your `create:` to something along the lines of:

```
create: function(input) {
    // append "clear all" anchor to top of search div
    $("#searchDiv").append('<a href="#" class="clearAll">Clear All</a>')

    // perform autocomplete AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url:  base_url + '/search-property-autocomplete',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: query,

        },
        error: function() {
            // add text
            return input;
        },
        success: function(res) {
            // TODO: do something to display the autocomplete results
            // e.g. create a dropdown with autcomplete suggestions
            // TODO: handle user selecting one of the suggestions

            // add text
            return input;
        }
    });


},
```

and fill out the necessary `TODO`s to get the functionality you desire.

HTH

Comment: Your Answer somehow helped me to solve or implement what I want. Hence I am selecting your answer to give bounty rewards. However, I provided my answer as final code if someone stuck to the same issue where I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve can be done a little differently.
Using **create** callback will create new items that aren't in the initial list of options when you select the **add ... option** shown on top. This is not what you want.

Just try:

```
var $select = $('#q').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    valueField: 'address',
    labelField: 'address',
    searchField: 'address',                 
    create: false,
    score: function() { return function() { return 1; }; },
    render: {
        item: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div>' + escape(data.address) + '</div>';
        }

    },
    onChange: function(value) {

      if(value == 'Clear All') {
          var control = $select[0].selectize;
          control.clearOptions();
      }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/search-property-autocomplete',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                q: query,

            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                // add the clear All option  on top.
                res.properties.unshift({address: "Clear All" });
                callback(res.properties);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This adds an extra option and uses onChange event to clear options when selected.

Also note the **score** option, so that the default filtering is disabled.